# How to see device orientation on Crittercism portal

Tags: android, crittercism

I am using Crittercism for Crash Reporting in my android app. The prob. is that am not able to figure out the way of finding device orientation on Crittercism web portal.

They must provide tutorial about how to use a feature. As their use base is not vast enough yet, hence rare chance of getting support on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>There is one way of getting device orientation by using Crittercism's Breadcrumbs, together with a call to display.getRotation().</strike>

This is a bit limited since you have to know approximately when in your code you would like to know the orientation, but it might help if you're narrowing down what triggers a bug, e.g. during development.

It looks like this information is actually already available in all crittercism crash reports:

1. Select the crash report you're interested in.
2. Go to the Diagnostics tab
3. Here you can find a breakdown of when that crash occurred under different conditions. Orientation is one of the conditions. There is also status bar orientation, along with a bunch of other info.

Comment: thank you. the thing was actually that "diagnostic" tab was not visible for me initially... when i read this, i tried generating same crash on both landscape/portrait mode . now after refresh screen, i was surprised that it is visible... may be a tiny bug..

Comment: @ShailendraSinghRajawat not a bug, but if you symbolicated the crash report then a new crash grouping was created. By design for bucketing purposes though we're looking into how to improve this experience.